# React.js 16.8 Bottom Nav fixed to top after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

The Navbar is currently positioned at the bottom of the view port and it need's to become fixed to the top as I scroll. I have tried mixing in jquery because that's how most tutorials that I have found use. If anyone has a solution using react.js I would really appreciate it. I currently have this:

```
const Navbar = () => {

  const main = document.querySelector('.home');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');


  window.onscroll = function () {

      if (window.pageYOffset > (main.offsetHeight - nav.offsetHeight)) {
          nav.classList.remove('bottom-nav');
          nav.classList.add('nav');
      } else {
          nav.classList.add('bottom-nav');
          nav.classList.remove('nav');

      }
  }
  return(
    <nav className="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

This is what the scss looks like:

```
.top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.bottom-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and other styling under just the html tag `nav`.

The error that I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
Navbar.window.onscroll
src/components/Navbar.jsx:12
   9 | 
  10 | window.onscroll = function () {
  11 | 
> 12 |     if (window.pageYOffset > (main.offsetHeight - nav.offsetHeight)) {
     | ^  13 |         nav.classList.remove('bottom-nav');
  14 |         nav.classList.add('nav');
  15 |     } else {
```

Comment: Make sure you have a DOM element with class `home` present.

Comment: @slumbergeist do you mean like on my second line of code? If you could teach me a little bit more I would really appreciate it. Thank you !

Comment: In the first 1st line, you are basically saying - if there is an HTML tag in my code which has the class `home`, fetch the details of that element and store it in a variable named `main`. Now the error you are getting is `Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null`. Here compiler is telling you that you are trying to access offsetHeight from a `null` value which should ideally be the HTML element stored at `main`. Hence, the first step should be to check your HTML if there is a tag with `home` class present. You might have misspelled or forgot to apply that class causing this issue.

Comment: @slumbergeist I have a class called home though. I moved the query logic to the file App.js, which imports all other pages and components (and specifically Navbar.js and Home.js). Both Home.js and Navbar.js have the classes of .home and .navbar.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since you are attaching scroll handler before the component is actually mounted. Move your scroll handler to App.js or parent component and initialize it after component has mounted. For this, you can use `componentDidMount` life-cycle hook if it is a class based component or `useEffect` hook if it is a functional component.

Also, the better "react" way would be using `props` to update components class.
Give your `navbar` component any `prop` to handle toggling of class. Let's say we add a new prop `sticky` to `navbar`. Then we can update it like this :

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  
  // we can directly use the prop value to update our classes

  return(
    <nav className={`navbar ${props.sticky ? 'nav' : 'bottom-nav'}`}>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
   )
 }
```

Then in our parent component we can maintain a state to track when the navbar component's class needs to be updated. We then pass the state down as prop to the child component.

```
--------------------
  App.js
--------------------

/**
 * Class based approach
 **/

constructor() {
   this.main = null;
   this.nav = null;
   this.state = {
      stickyHeader: false
   }
}


componentDidMount() { 
   // we can safely store these values in instance variable
   // so that we just have to query the DOM once
   this.main = document.querySelector('.home');
   this.nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');

   window.onscroll = function () {
   
   if (window.pageYOffset > (main.offsetHeight - nav.offsetHeight)) {
      this.setState({stickyHeader: true});
   } else {
      this.setState({stickyHeader: false});
    }
  }
}

render() {
   ....
   <NavBar sticky={this.state.stickyHeader} />
   
}

/**
 * Functional component approach
 **/

// useRef value remains constant across render
// so we use it to define our variables
const main = useRef(null);
const nav = useRef(null);

// local state to keep track of navbar updates
const [stickyHeader, updateStickyHeader] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => { 
  // on mount query and update refs value
  main.current = document.querySelector('.home');
  nav.current = document.querySelector('.navbar');

  window.onscroll = function () {

   if (window.pageYOffset > (main.current.offsetHeight - nav.current.offsetHeight)) {
      updateStickyHeader(true);
   } else {
      updateStickyHeader(false);
    }
  }

}, [])

return (
  <>
    ...
    <NavBar sticky={this.state.stickyHeader} />
  </>
```

I would recommend you to read more about React [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to understand better.